# Symfony - Using only DI

Tags: dependency-injection, symfony

Is it possible to set up Symfony only with the services & ORM - and no controller? Can external scripts bootstrap with the Kernel and leverage DI? What is the approach/best practice?

Or let's say.. a controller *can be* present, but external scripts also bootstrap with the kernel.

**Edit: This is what i can think of, and it works, but i'm not sure if it is the best way**

Have some sort of an init.php which i can require in my existing scripts, and declare a global `$Symfony` object which actually is what is returned by `$kernel->getContainer()`. And then from that `get("service_id")` and carry on.

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$kernel->boot();
$Symfony = $kernel->getContainer();
$service = $Symfony->get('service_id');
```

Comment: What exactly is your goal? Could you describe it on some example?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your problem but it may interest you: [How to Define Controllers as Services (The Symfony CookBook)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html).

Comment: What you mean with external scripts? A PHP flat files? You want to access the container services by them?

Comment: By external scripts i mean a non-symfony php script (say index.php) which can call Symfony services. I have an existing project that has http set up, that's a large existing php application and i want to drive it to a DI architecture.. This is more like an interim phase until we get most of the stuff migrated over to Symfony and set it up along with controllers like they should be used.

Comment: try something like this:        `global $kernel;if ( 'AppCache' == get_class($kernel) ){$kernel = $kernel->getKernel();}
        $translator = $kernel->getContainer()->get('translator');`